# Group by Similar 2 fields in php and result with total count?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

How to Group two Similar fields in php?

I tried with GROUP BY DATE(bill.date) , bill.agent_id but it is not working for me

Table Structure 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvBF0.jpg (table name is bill_agents )
 Table Structure 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38tKh.jpg (table name is bill )

Current Result

```
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
|         |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
| Agent 1 | 35 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 | 10 |  0 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 1 |  0 |  0 | 12 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 3 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100 |  0 |
| Agent 6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 | 14 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

1,2,3,4,5 .... are the days from date

**But I want To get Like The Following**

```
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
|         |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |total
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
| Agent 1 | 35 |  0 | 12 |   0 |  0 |47  |
| Agent 2 |  0 | 10 |  0 |   0 | 14 |28  |
| Agent 3 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100 |  0 |100 |
| Agent 6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  0 | 9  |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
```

Php Code pasted below that I am using now .

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <?php
for ($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
  {?>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <?php

  }
?>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <?php 

    $query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
          "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
          "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ". 
          "GROUP BY bill.agent_id , DATE(bill.date)   ".

              // "GROUP BY bill.agent_id , DATE(bill.date)  ".
              "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";

    $result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die('Error, query failed1'); 
    if  (mysql_num_rows($result4)>0){
    mysql_data_seek($result4, 0);   

?>
  <?php $total_1 = 0;  while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
  <?php $date =    $row4['date'];

    $var = $date;
    $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($var) );
    $date=substr($date, 0, -8); 

    echo $date;

    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row4['name']; ?></td>
    <?php
for ($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
  {?>
    <td><?php if ($date == $i) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <?php

  }
?>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } } ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="31"></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should definitely structure your code better. It's really hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't know if I understood your question here is a short sample which could point you in the right direction:

```
$query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, "
        . "       bill.date, "
        . "       SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total, "
        . "       bill_agents.id, "
        . "       bill_agents.name "
        . "FROM bill, bill_agents "
        . "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id "
        . "AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) "
        . "AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) "
        . "GROUP BY bill.agent_id, DATE(bill.date)   "
        . "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";

$result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die('Error, query failed1');
if (mysql_num_rows($result4) > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($result4, 0);

    $agents = array();
    while (true == ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4))) {
        $agents[$row4['agent_id']][$row4['date']] = $row4;
    } 

    var_dump($agents);
}
```

Take a look at the output and see if you can work further with that `$agents` variable.

Comment: That result looks like pretty awesome but im not sure that if i can applay that into my loop